# SharePoint Permissions

Tags: sharepoint

I have a custom workflow. This workflow removes permissions to items when an item is added (example an item is added by a service account and once added those permissions need to be removed from that item).  This works as I have the service account 'hard coded' in the custom workflow.

Now I would like to remove this hard coding and when a item is added to a list I would like to iterate through all users that have access to the list item.  If a user matches some algorithm then remove that user from the item permissions which will be 0 to many.

The piece I'm stuggling with is how to iterage all users with permission to a SPListItem.  Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [`SPListItem.RoleAssignments` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.roleassignments%28v=office.12%29.aspx) which is a collection of [`SPRoleAssignment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms454030%28v=office.12%29.aspx) objects. The `Member` property then represents a specific `SPUser` or `SPGroup` object that is assigned specific permissions in respect to the given list item by binding it to a collection of role definitions.

In your case you need to iterate over all available role assignments, inspect those that denote principals (users or groups) matching your criteria and rearrange the role assignments in a way that fits the desired security policy.

Answer (score 0):

I think I just found the answer to this.  I can iterate the RoleAssignments collection and perform my check on that.  If anyone has another other ideas I'd be curious to hear about them :)

Thanks1